# Issue when trying to connect explorer with Hyperledger fabric network hosted on different machines

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I am setting up explorer for fabric network which was running in some different machine(say IP 12.34.56.78),when i try to start the script start.sh from explorer i struck with this error.
Successfully connected on single instance(both explorer and fabric on a single machine) but facing error when trying to connect on different machines.

Here is the config.json file where i am changing parameters.

```js
{
  "network-configs": {
    "network-1": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "clients": {
        "client-1": {
          "tlsEnable": true,
          "organization": "Org1MSP",
          "channel": "mychannel",
          "credentialStore": {
            "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
            "cryptoStore": {
              "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
          "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
          },
          "connection": {
            "timeout": {
              "peer": {
                "endorser": "6000",
                "eventHub": "6000",
                "eventReg": "6000"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org1MSP",
          "fullpath": false,
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/dinesh/HyperExplorer/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
          },
          "signedCert": {
            "path": "/home/dinesh/HyperExplorer/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
          }
        },
        "Org2MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org2MSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/dinesh/HyperExplorer/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        },
        "OrdererMSP": {
          "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/home/dinesh/HyperExplorer/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        }
      },
      "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/home/dinesh/HyperExplorer/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpcs://12.34.56.78:7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://l12.34.56.78:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://12.34.56.78:8051"
        },
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://12.34.56.78:9051"
        },
        "peer1.org2.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://12.34.56.78:10051"
        }
      },
      "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://12.34.56.78:7050"
        }
      }
    },
    "network-2": {}
  },
  "configtxgenToolPath": "/home/dinesh/HyperExplorer/fabric-samples/bin",
  "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

---

### Error

> (node:16024) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader
>   module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
>   2019-05-28T13:26:18.102Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to
>   connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7050
>   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {
>   Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
>   URL:grpcs://localhost:7050
>       at checkState (/home/dinesh/Music/blockchain-explorer-master/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:720:16)
>   connectFailed: true }

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the discovery options in your SDK?

Here the link to the discovery options in the official HL NodeJS Fabric SDK documentation.

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Gateway.html#~DiscoveryOptions

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the IP address of the explorer machine on the fabric network, also copy the permission file from the fabric network machine to explorer machine, similar to the sftp protocol

Comment: Where can i put my explorer ip in fabric network setup

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set environment variable **DISCOVERY_AS_LOCALHOST** to **false** in **start.sh** file. That was the reason you saw: localhost.

Ensure check explorerconfig.json if sync process is running from different locations

```
 "sync": {
    "type": "host"
 }
```